# Parameterized grouping in join query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, left-join, laravel-5.3

I have three tables: `admins`, `users` and  `maintenances` with the following structure.

`admins` table: (type=1)

```
admin_id admin_name admin_table  theme ... 
1           A         ..
2           B         ..
```

`users` table (type=2):

```
user_id user_name
1           A
2           B
3           C
```

`maintenances` table:

```
maintenance_id  requester_type  requester payer_type payer
1                    2             3         2        3
1                    2             4         1        1
1                    2             1         2        1
1                    1             1         1        1
```

I need to get the user details and count of maintenances. Maintenances can be counted for user if either requester or payer  is that user.

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(m.maintenance_id) as maintenanceCount 
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN maintenances as m ON ((m.requester_type=2 AND m.requester_id=u.user_id) OR (m.payer_type=2 AND m.payer_id=u.user_id))
GROUP BY user_id
```

With laravel query builder, I tried:

```
DB::table('users as u')
   ->leftjoin('maintenances as m', function($join){
              $join->on('m.requester_type', '=', DB::raw(2))
              ->where('m.requester_id', 'u.user_id');
    })
   ->groupby('user_id')
   ->select('u.*', DB::raw('Count(m.maintenance_id) as maintenanceCount)')->get();
```

but this is wrong. How can I group conditions for joining in Laravel query builder? Can someone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   DB::table('users as u')
   ->leftjoin('maintenances as m', function($join){
              $join
                  ->where(function ($on) {
                      $on->where('m.requester_type', 2)
                         ->whereRaw('m.requester_id = u.user_id');
                  })
                  ->orWhere(function ($on) {
                      $on->where('m.payer_type', 2)
                         ->whereRaw('m.payer_id = u.user_id');
                  });
    })
   ->groupby('user_id')
   ->select('u.*', DB::raw('Count(m.maintenance_id) as maintenanceCount)')->get();
```